# Getting the field editor of NSTextField before editing

Tags: cocoa

I got a resizable height of multi line NSTextField. It uses the field editor (NSTextView) to get the size of the text container using the NSLayoutManger's method usedRectForTextContainer:.

However, if I initially set the string of my text field before any editing using the method setStringValue:, the calculation fails for the height because field editor for the text field is NULL (return by fieldEditor:forObject:)

How to get the field editor of a text field before any editing of the text field?

Comment: Does the `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` method [control:textShouldBeginEditing:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSControlTextEditingDelegate/control:textShouldBeginEditing:]) give you access to the field editor at an early enough stage?

Comment: Maybe I should mimic the field editor by explicitly create an NSTextView that match the NSTextField property?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. This seems like a common enough use case. Research all method/notifications that return a field editor, see what you can do. Doesn't the window hold the field editor for all its controls?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can only get the field editor (NSTextView) of a NSTextField after you begin the editing of the text field.

An excerpt from Apple documentation:

> The text system automatically instantiates the field editor from the
>   NSTextView class when the user begins editing text of an NSControl
>   object such as a text field

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I just had the same issue. In my case, I need to modify the string that the user will edit BEFORE the editor appears (so before control:textShouldBeginEditing). So, for future visitors to this thread:

My solution was to subclass the NSTextField, and then override becomeFirstResponder:

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    self.stringValue = self.editableName;
    return [super becomeFirstResponder];
}
```